# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'count'

Tags: python

Can someone please help me?
I keep getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'count'

Here's my code:

```
fin=open("ah_d_01_CGATGT_L003_R1_001.fastq","r")
fout=open("ah_d_01_CGATGT_L003_R1_001.filt.fastq","w")
maxN=4
contatutte=containcl=0
seq=""
for line in fin:
    seq=fin.readline
    ctrl=fin.readline
    qual=fin.readline
    countN=seq.count("N", start=0, end=len(seq))
    if maxN>countN:
        fout.write(line)  #eventualmente aggiungi +"\n"
        fout.write(seq)
        fout.write(ctrl)
        fout.write(qual)
        containcl+=1
fin.close
fout.close
print contatutte,containcl
```

Thanks

Comment: Note that `seq=""` but also `seq=fin.readline`... I think you wanted some parentheses.

Comment: there no need for `fin.readline` since you are already iterating over it just use `line`

Comment: in the call `seq.count(`, the `start` and `end` parameters are redundant/unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your functions properly. In Python you can not omit the `()`.

```
...
for line in fin:
    seq=fin.readline()
    ctrl=fin.readline()
    qual=fin.readline()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make two changes in your code:

1. `seq += fin.read()`
2. `countN = seq.count("N", 0, len(seq))`

below code don't have any error but you have to make some changes according to your algorithm

```
fin=open("README.txt","r")
fout=open("submittest.txt","w")
maxN=4
contatutte=containcl=0
seq=""
seq += fin.read()
ctrl=fin.read()
qual=fin.read()
countN = seq.count("N", 0, len(seq))
if maxN>countN:
    #fout.write(line)  #eventualmente aggiungi +"\n"
    fout.write(seq)
    fout.write(ctrl)
    fout.write(qual)
    containcl+=1

fin.close
fout.close
print contatutte,containcl
```

or

```
fout=open("submittest.txt","w")
maxN=1000
contatutte=containcl=0
seq=""

with open('README.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        seq += line
        ctrl = line
        qual = line
        countN = seq.count("N", 0, len(seq))
        if maxN>countN:
            #fout.write(line)  #eventualmente aggiungi +"\n"
            fout.write(seq)
            fout.write(ctrl)
            fout.write(qual)
            containcl+=1

        if 'str' in line:
            break

fout.close
print contatutte,containcl
```

Comment: Thanks; I tried but I received this error: ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

Comment: let me see what changes you made??

Comment: 'fin=open("ah_d_01_CGATGT_L003_R1_001.fastq","r")
fout=open("ah_d_01_CGATGT_L003_R1_001.filt.fastq","w")
maxN=4
contatutte=containcl=0
seq=("")
for line in fin:
    seq +=fin.read()
    ctrl=fin.read()
    qual=fin.read()
    countN=seq.count("N" ,0, len(seq))
    if maxN>countN:
        fout.write(line) # +"\n"
        fout.write(seq)
        fout.write(ctrl)
        fout.write(qual)
        containcl+=1
fin.close
fout.close
print contatutte,containcl'

Comment: post a different question with detais and give me link

Comment: you dont have to use for loop in case of fin.read()  #read my code carefully#